# PHP Function two loops from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, function, loops

I've got 2 tables one holds questions and one holds answers. I was wondering if I can grab and echo them through a function. So basically loop through the questions and echo question + answers.

```
Questions
+------+-------------------------------+
| q_id | question                      |
+------+-------------------------------+
| 1    | What is your favorite color?  |
+------+-------------------------------+

Answers
+------+------+-----------+
| a_id | q_id | answer    |
+------+------+-----------+
| 1    | 1    | Green     |
+------+------+-----------+
| 2    | 1    | Blue      |
+------+------+-----------+
| 3    | 1    | Yellow    |
+------+------+-----------+
```

What I have done until now

```
function Questionaire()
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }

    $result = array();

    $conn = $this->connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE status = 1";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $result[] = $row['question'];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about JOIN - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function Questionaire()
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }

    $data = array();

    $conn = $this->connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE status = 1";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $row['answers'] = [];
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE q_id = '$row[q_id]'";
        $result2 = $conn->query($query2);
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch())$row['answers'][] = $row2;
        echo "Question: <pre>".var_export($row, true)."</pre>";
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: I messed up the $result parts :P This almost does the trick! Any suggestion on how I can group them up because right now I've tried $result['question'] and got a full list of questions but without any answers with them. Thanks!

Comment: Now I see, I updated my answer to do what you want. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the question `q_id` as the `$results` array key, and the result as an array ->

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE status = 1";
$result = $conn->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $result[$row['q_id']] = array('question'=> $row['question']);
}
```

Then perform a similar fetch with the answers, using the `q_id` to link to the question, and the `a_id` as the key in the `answers` array ->

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `answers`";
$result = $conn->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $result[$row['q_id']]['answers'][$row['a_id']] = $row['answer'];
}
```

This will result in a `$result` value of -

```
$result = array( 
             1=> array( 
                    'question' => 'What is your favorite color?',
                    'answers' => array(
                                    1 => 'Green',
                                    2 => 'Blue',
                                    3 => 'Yellow'
                                 )
                  ), 
             2=> array( 
                    'question' => ...
          );
```